# How to ensure node.js child_process.spawn will write error messages to the console

Tags: windows, node.js

I'm having a lot of trouble running child processes and getting their output written to the console. In this episode, I'm trying to use `spawn` to run a windows `mklink` command. The error is the that I don't have permission to write the file.

*My* problem, though, is that the error isn't told to me in any way.

The following prints `You do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.` to the console:

`mklink /D C:\some\path\to\my\intended\link C:\path\to\my\folder`

But running this in node.js only gives me `Error: spawn ENOENT` - which is a highly useless error message:

```
require('child_process').spawn('mklink', 
         ['/D', 'C:\\some\\path\\to\\my\\intended\\link', 
                'C:\\path\\to\\my\\folder'],
         {stdio:'inherit'})
```

I get nothing on the console, despite the stdio:'inherit'. I've also tried the following:

```
var x = require('child_process').spawn('mklink', 
         ['/D', 'C:\\some\\path\\to\\my\\intended\\link', 
                'C:\\path\\to\\my\\folder'])
x.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
x.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
```

But no dice. No console output at all. Note that I *do* get console output with `exec`:

```
var x = require('child_process')
         .exec('mklink /D C:\\some\\path\\to\\my\\intended\\link C:\\path\\to\\my\\folder')
x.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
x.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
```

This shouldn't need any special knowledge of how windows mklink works - my problem is simply with error reporting with node.js `spawn`.

What am I doing wrong here? Is this a bug in node.js?

**Update**: It seems this bug has been fixed by node v0.10.29

Comment: What happens if you use `mklink` from `spawn()` or `exec()` with a `.exe` after it?

Comment: Same problem with that, in fact its also the same problem if i use gibberish as the command. You think spawn just can't find mklink? Even so, the problem remains the same: I need better error responses out of spawn.

Comment: The child process module generally just doesn't work as intended on Windows, and most people attempting to use them on Windows get what you're getting, which is `ENOENT`.

Comment: Alright, I'll write a bug ticket for it, thanks

Comment: Are you 100% sure the `mklink` executable itself is found by `spawn()` or `exec()`? Failing at that would explain everything. (BTW, I'm using `child_process` on Windows, and so far I've got ENOENT in that case only.)

Comment: It runs properly when using sudo, which proves it can find mklink.

Answer (score 1):

For me `stdio` wasn't working.

Try this:

```
    // Helper function to execute and log out child process
    // TODO: implement a better success/error callback
    var spawnProcess = function(command, args, options, callback) {
        var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
        var process = spawn(command, args, options),
            err = false;

        process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
            grunt.log.write(data);
        });

        process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
            err = true;
            grunt.log.errorlns(data);
        });

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            process.on('exit', function() {
                if (!err) {
                    return callback();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    spawnProcess('mklink', ['/D', 'C:\\some\\path\\to\\my\\intended\\link', 'C:\\path\\to\\my\\folder'], {}, done);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try the following:

```
require('child_process').spawn('cmd', 
     ['/C', 'mklink', '/D', 'C:\\some\\path\\to\\my\\intended\\link', 
            'C:\\path\\to\\my\\folder'],
     {stdio:'inherit'})
```